# Need help optimizing a sieve of Eratosthenes in c++

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've been working on a Sieve of Eratosthenes for a few days now. It's an assignment for school that is due today and I have to head over to work. The code works perfect, however, I would like to optimize this into a loop, rather than listing the prime divisors... any suggestions?

```
void Eratos(int num, vector<int>&primes)
{
    int i;
    //we are setting up the variable for use
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)
{
    primes.push_back(i);
}

for (i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
{
    if ((primes.at(i) % 2 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 2))
    {
        //if i is divisible by 2 change value to zero... and so on until 13
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 3 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 3))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 5 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 5))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 7 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 7))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 13 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 13))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 17 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 17))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 19 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 19))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if ((primes.at(i) % 23 == 0) && (primes.at(i) != 23))
    {
        primes.at(i) = 0;
    }
    if (primes.at(i) == 0)
    {
        //erase all '0' values from vector
        primes.erase(primes.begin() + i); 

        //keep place
        --i;
    }
```

(sorry if the formatting was weird, this is my first post here)

Comment: This is better posted to CodeReview@StackExchange.com

Comment: You could start by only placing odd values into the vector and removing the check for 2.

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't test for divisibility. First cross out all multiples of 2 (you find them by repeated addition by 2). Then cross out all multiples of the next prime (repeated addition by that number), and the next, and the next....

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep a list of ALL numbers!

Keep a list of the primes you've found and only try to divide the number under test with the found primes.